# Unhide / hide a class

Tags: javascript

everyone.

I'm trying to use an a href link to "onclick" toggle unhide and hide. I've tried using jQuery, javascript functions, but I just don't seem to know quite enough to make it work. I've gotten close. This is what I have now (my 8th or so attempt)

styles.css:

```
.noPhones{
    display: none;
}
```

The javascript (contacts.tpl):

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapMyToggledDiv()
{
if(document.getElementById(".noPhones").style.display == "none")
{
document.getElementById(".noPhones").style.display = "block";
}
else
{
document.getElementById(".noPhones").style.display = "none";
}</script>
{/literal}
```

My forms (contacts.tpl):

```
        <tr><td>
            <h2><a href="#" onclick="swapMyToggledDiv()">Phone</a></h2>
        </td><td>
            <input type="hidden" name="phone[contactId]" value="{$userData.contact_id}" />
            <input type="text" name="phone[tel]" size="25" value="{$userData.telTel}" />
        </td></tr>

        <tr class="noPhones"><td>
            <h2>Cell #</h2>
        </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="phone[cell]" size="25" value="{$userData.telCell}" />
        </td></tr>

        <tr class="noPhones"><td>
            <h2>Work #</h2>
        </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="phone[work]" size="25" value="{$userData.telWork}" />
        </td></tr>

        <tr class="noPhones"><td>
            <h2>Home #</h2>
        </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="phone[home]" size="25" value="{$userData.telHome}" />
        </td></tr>

        <tr class="noPhones"><td>
            <h2>Pager #</h2>
        </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="phone[pager]" size="25" value="{$userData.telPager}" />
        </td></tr>

        <tr class="noPhones"><td>
            <h2>Fax</h2>
        </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="phone[fax]" size="25" value="{$userData.telFax}" />
        </td></tr>
```

I need all the rows with class "noPhones" hidden until clicking the link.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggling visibility in jQuery is straightforward:

```
function swapMyToggledDiv()
{
    $( ".noPhones" ).toggle();
}
```

If you apply an ID to your link, you can apply this action in the jQuery onready method:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#toggle_link" ).click( function() {
        $( ".noPhones" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Holy moly! I was making this way too complicated! That did it. I've been at it for 2 hours!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @George Thanks so much! I'm using the jQuery version, and it works great. In this particular situation, can you tell me why the jQuery solution is better than the plain old JS? Both seem to work great.

Comment: @SquireCD: One is not necessarily better than the other, so I would recommend the one that you like better. I think the jQuery version is a little cleaner because you won't have to include Javascript calls in the `<a>`. It is often better on developers if we don't have to switch in and out of jQuery/plain Javascript modes when we don't have to, so the jQuery-only method is easer (for me) to comprehend.

Answer (score 2):

and you can't have `document.getElementById(".noPhones")`

you need to give an id attribute not a class

Answer (score 2):

Jquery is very neat.  You should use it.  It is EXTREMELY simple.

Just do this.

Step 1: Include Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Step 2: set the onclick to call a function "testFunction()"

Step 3: Define the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testFunction() {
    $('.noPhones').hide();  or $('.noPhones').show();
    // The $('.noPhones') selector selects all of the objects with a class of "noPhones"
    // use $('#id') to select an item by ID
    }
</script>
```

If you want to do something when the page loads just do this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ //define function here });
    // Stuff defined in function will execute on page load.
</script>
```

Hope this helps
I LOVE JQUERY

Comment: You asked why use JQuery vs. Javascript.  The main reason is browser compatibility.  We have a whole team where I work that is dedicated to browser compatibility issues that are from using Javascript.  JQuery is a black box that hides the troubles that come from supporting multiple browsers / platforms.  Always go with JQuery when it is an option.