# JAVASCRIPT - Unhiding a Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a class in my HTML file, which is set to hidden in my external CSS file. The class is titled "a."

In my CSS file, I have done this:

```
.a{
    display: none;
}
```

In my external Javscript file, I want to unhide this class. How would I do this? I have currently tried the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('a').style.visibility = visible/block;
```

But this hasn't worked.

Thank you.

Comment: The most simplest way would be to remove the class from the elements having it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhide / hide a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684545/unhide-hide-a-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one `visible/block` isn't a valid property value for either `display` or `visibility`.
In the CSS you use `display` but in your JS you are using `visibility` so you don't overwrite the CSS.

Also note that [`document.getElementsByClassName('a')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) doesn't return just one item as is the case with [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Take a look at the following example to see how it does work.

```js
const as = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
const trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');

trigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for( let a of as) 
  {
    a.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
.a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Block A
</div>

<div class="a">
  Block B
</div>

<div class="a">
  Block C
</div>

<button id="trigger">Show A</button>
```

The above example works with multiple `class="a"` elements but if you don't want that you can replace the `for`-loop with:

```
as[0].style.display = 'block';
```

You can also the following to hide and unhide the element(s):

```
if(a.style.display === 'none')
{
  a.style.display = 'block';
} else {
  a.style.display = 'none';
}
```

As suggested adding/ removing (toggle) class:

```js
const as = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
const trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');

trigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for( let a of as) 
  {
    a.classList.toggle('b');
  }
});
```

```css
.a {
  display: none;
}

.b {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Block A
</div>

<div class="a">
  Block B
</div>

<div class="a">
  Block C
</div>

<button id="trigger">Show A</button>
```

Or to remove the `.a` class:

```
a.classList.remove('a');
```

This does however also removes the possibility to hide the element(s) again since the selector is removed from the element.

Comment: Overriding a CSS class with online style seems odd, why not just replace the class with another class or remove the class from the elements ..?

Comment: @Teemu Yes I know. Have added those now as well. But also wanted to show the possibilities the OP has with the code provided.

Comment: Thank you so much! This not only helped my program work, but also gave me tons of new info to learn.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection. To modify the style of an element, you'll need to specify which one.

In your case, you're using the `display` style in the stylesheet, but you're trying to reverse that with the `visibility` style. These are similar styles with different uses.

`visibility: hidden` will hide the element with the `a` class but will not move its sibling elements when it is set as `visibility: visibile`.

`display: none` will hide the element with the `a` class, and its siblings will move out of the way when its style is set to `block`.

If you'd like to preserve the location of your `a` class element, you should change your stylesheet to `visibility: hidden` and unhide it with:

`document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].style.visibility = 'visibile';`

If you'd like to stick with your current stylesheet, you can unhide it with:

`document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].style.display = 'block';`

If you have multiple elements with that class, and you'd like to unhide them all at once, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36961002/8108612) should put you on track for unhiding all of them by looping over the HTMLCollection.

Comment: How would this help? The rule in the stylesheet is `display:none`, and who knows how many `.a` elements there are in OP's HTML? And further, `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, it returns a NodeList object.

Comment: Yeah, this didn't make them visible. I've tried visible and block, but neither seemed to work.